# SQL Server 2008 R2 trigger identity column

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, identity

I need to create a trigger to add a record to second table.

- First table : `tab_esami`
- Second table : `tab_valutazioni`

I create this trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NewTrigger]
ON [dbo].[tab_esame]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    /* Trigger action goes here. */
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT TAB_VALUTAZIONI ON

    INSERT INTO tab_valutazioni(tab_utenti_id, nume_colesterolo,
                                nume_hdl, nume_ldl, nume_trigliceridi,
                                nume_glicemia, data_insert)
        SELECT 
            id_paziente, colesterolo_totale,
            hdl, ldl, trigliceridi,
            glicemia, data_esame
        FROM 
            INSERTED
END
GO
```

But when I try to insert a record into `tab_esami` I get an error :

[Error_ON_insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3biz2.jpg)

Can you help me?

The `id` column for `tab_valutazioni` is 'ID' and it is a primary key with autoincrement properties..

Thanks

Comment: You also never close parenthesis after opening it after `SELECT(` and you have `GO'` Should be just `GO`

Comment: I would recommend **not** to insert any values into `tab_valutazioni.ID` (you don't seem to be doing that right now), and let SQL Server handle the auto-increment ID itself. In that case, you **don't need** the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TAB_VALUTAZIONI ON` setting and should remove it from your trigger. **ALSO:** whenever you turn this setting **ON** for a table - make sure to turn if back **OFF** once you've done your insert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this code to work properly you should set Identity Column. See this.
[image]